# How do identities with specific domains work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have the identity $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x+1$ for all $x$, we can substitute, $x^2 = 5x$ (lets call this step $1$) into it, to get $(x+1)^2 = 7x + 1$ for all $x$ such that $5x =x^2$ which is just $x=0 $ and $x=5$. I would like to ask, what are we actually doing in step $1$, and why is all $x$ the "standard" domain for the indentity? As in if you write down an identity why is it that without "modifying" it and using a condition such as $x^2 = 5x$, it remains true for all $x$?

Answer (score 0):

When you assume that $x^2=5x$ you limit the domain of the identity because $x^2=5x$ is not true for all x values. However, if we know that x is in a field, we can expand $(x+1)^2$ using the axioms of a field, and the axioms of a field are true for all x in the field.

Comment: Alright, and I guess we do not have a condition for $x^2$ in the case that the identity holds for all $x$ as there is no general statement relating $x^2$ to $x$ (other than its definition for all $x$)?